# Is CJ7 alive at the end of the movie?

Tags: plot-explanation, cj7

In the movie *CJ7* there is a UFO.

There are many CJ7 like creatures. The one in the front looks like the CJ7 that's in the rest of the movie.

Is this meant to be the same CJ7. Did CJ7's soul go up and got moved to the UFO?

> In the end, Dicky sees a UFO landing and many other alien dogs like
>   CJ7 of different colors and patterns come out and realizes that the
>   CJ7s are headed by **his very own toy**.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CJ7

Is it his own toy or just something that looks like the original CJ7? What's the explanation?

Comment: Sadly, even today, quick searching on Google doesn't return relevant results about it but this question